# How can I create a popup menu in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I create a popup menu like the one present in WhatsApp?

[image: Screenshot of the popup menu]

Sorry for the dumb question, but I don't even know what to search. I'm pretty sure it's not a `UIPickerView`.

Comment: You should review the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) before posting a question like this.

Comment: The basic problem is the naming making it hard to find the solution UIAlertController  but this question is actually a connector between the question and the answer. Good question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an **action sheet**. [Here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/) about it in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

You can make one like this:

### SwiftUI (iOS 15 and above)

Use `confirmationDialog()`. [Here is the official documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:message:)-8y541) and [here are some real-world examples, which are partially the source of the example code.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-action-sheet)

```
@State private var shouldShowActionSheet = false

<custom view>
.confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $shouldShowActionSheet) {
    Button("Option 1") {
        <handler>
    }

    Button("Option 2") {
        <handler>
    }

    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
}
```

### SwiftUI (iOS 13 and 14)

```
@State private var shouldShowActionSheet = false

[...]

<custom view>
.actionSheet(isPresented: $shouldShowActionSheet) {
    ActionSheet(
        title: Text(""),
        buttons: [
            .default(Text("Option 1")) {
                <handler>
            },
            .default(Text("Option 2")) {
                <handler>
            },
            .cancel()
        ]
    )
}
```

### UIKit

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: nil,
    message: nil, 
    preferredStyle: .actionSheet
)

alert.addAction(
    .init(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { _ in
        <handler>
    }
)

alert.addAction(
    .init(title: "Action 2", style: .default) { _ in
        <handler>
    }
)

alert.addAction(.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: On this excellent answer, just a note that in all cases with a popup, you inevitably need to simply add a `.cancel` action.  Simply add an action with style `.cancel`.  importantly, this also takes care of when the user clicks "anywhere else on the screen" to dismiss the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Its `UIAlertController` with preferredStyle - `UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller